# Angular 8 Reactive Form dynamic Edit/Add modal validation

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a dynamic modal that can be reuse for add a user and edit, i successfully add the users to an array, but when i retrieve the data the validation still say is invalid even when the input is filled with the data from the array, so the error message is display when i select and live the input, the update button is disabled, i have to erase or add a character to "force" the validation, i appreciate any help.

this is how it what i did to show the value in the input:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="nameR"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="nameR"
            placeholder="* NOMBRE"
            [value]="editMode ? receiverData[editRecIndex].nameR : ''"
          />
          <small
            class="form-text text-danger"
            *ngIf="
              !receiverForm.get('nameR').valid &&
              (receiverForm.get('nameR').touched ||
                receiverForm.get('nameR').dirty)
            "
          >
            El nombre es requerido, mínimo 3 caracteres.
          </small>
```

component.ts

```
    import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-invoice',
  templateUrl: './new-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-invoice.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class NewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  searchSender: FormGroup;
  senderForm: FormGroup;
  receiverForm: FormGroup;
  modalTitle: string;
  modalContent: any;
  editMode = false;
  editRecIndex: number;
  countryRArray = ['venezuela', 'colombia'];
  receiverData = [];
  packageList = [];

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchSender = new FormGroup({
      dniS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
      ])
    });
    this.senderForm = new FormGroup({
      dniSen: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
      ]),
      nameS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      lnameS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      mobileS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6)
      ]),
      phoneS: new FormControl(null),
      emailS: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      countryS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      cityS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      locationS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      cpS: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2)
      ]),
      addressS: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
    this.receiverForm = new FormGroup({
      dniR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
      ]),
      nameR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      lnameR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      mobileR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6)
      ]),
      phoneR: new FormControl(null),
      additionalPhoneR: new FormControl(null),
      countryR: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      cityR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      locationR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      cpR: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2)
      ]),
      addressR: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  onAddPackage(addPack) {
    this.modalService.open(addPack, {
      windowClass: 'exp-modal'
    });
  }

  modalWin(size, scope, title, edit: boolean, index: number) {
    this.editMode = edit;
    switch (size) {
      case 'lg':
        this.modalService.open(scope, {
          size: 'lg'
        });
        break;
      case 'xl':
        this.modalService.open(scope, {
          windowClass: 'exp-modal'
        });
        break;
      default:
        this.modalService.open(scope, {
          size: 'sm'
        });
        break;
    }
    this.modalTitle = title;
    this.editRecIndex = index;
  }

  onAddReceiver() {
    const receiverData = {
      dniR: this.receiverForm.controls['dniR'].value,
      nameR: this.receiverForm.controls['nameR'].value,
      lnameR: this.receiverForm.controls['lnameR'].value,
      mobileR: this.receiverForm.controls['mobileR'].value,
      phoneR: this.receiverForm.controls['phoneR'].value,
      additionalPhoneR: 
      this.receiverForm.controls['additionalPhoneR'].value,
      countryR: this.receiverForm.controls['countryR'].value,
      cityR: this.receiverForm.controls['cityR'].value,
      locationR: this.receiverForm.controls['locationR'].value,
      cpR: this.receiverForm.controls['cpR'].value,
      addressR: this.receiverForm.controls['addressR'].value
    };

    this.receiverData.push(receiverData);
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    this.receiverForm.reset();
  }

  onEditReceiver(index: number) {
    const replaceReceiver = {
      ...this.receiverData[index],
      dniR: this.receiverForm.controls['dniR'].value,
      nameR: this.receiverForm.controls['nameR'].value,
      lnameR: this.receiverForm.controls['lnameR'].value,
      mobileR: this.receiverForm.controls['mobileR'].value,
      phoneR: this.receiverForm.controls['phoneR'].value,
      additionalPhoneR: 
      this.receiverForm.controls['additionalPhoneR'].value,
      countryR: this.receiverForm.controls['countryR'].value,
      cityR: this.receiverForm.controls['cityR'].value,
      locationR: this.receiverForm.controls['locationR'].value,
      cpR: this.receiverForm.controls['cpR'].value,
      addressR: this.receiverForm.controls['addressR'].value
    };

    const upReceiver = [
      ...this.receiverData.slice(0, index),
      replaceReceiver,
      ...this.receiverData.slice(index + 1)
    ];

    this.receiverData = upReceiver;
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    this.receiverForm.reset();
  }
```

i know is a little bit mess, but right now i'm working on functionality then i will make service and all the stuff

Comment: You might have to provide in more implementation detail. Would it be possible to create a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue?

Comment: Did you try resetting the form using `form.resetForm()` before loading the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to resolve this after cleaning a lot of code, i call my modal passing some args, the modal reference, editMode status and the index of the data, what i did is to setValue() to the form and pass the data from the array, this way it fill the inputs with the selected data and the data pass all validations requirements.

```
onReceiverModal(modal, editMode?: boolean, index?: number) {
this.editReceiver = editMode;
if (editMode) {
  this.receiverForm.setValue(this.receiverData[index]);
}
this.editReceiverIndex = index;
this.modalService.open(modal, {
  size: 'lg',
  windowClass: 'dark-modal'
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is, generate the form only after the data is retrieved. Something like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { delay, map } from "rxjs/operators";

import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Component({
  selector: "ngbd-modal-basic",
  templateUrl: "./modal-basic.html"
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult: string;
  receiverForm$: Observable<FormGroup>;
  data$: Observable<any> = of({ nameR: "John" }).pipe(delay(500));

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.receiverForm$ = this.data$.pipe(
      map(res =>
        this.fb.group({
          nameR: [res.nameR, Validators.required]
        })
      )
    );
  }

  open(content) {
    ...
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    ...
  }
}
```

And once that happens, you could then safely patch it to the template using the `async` pipe:

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <form *ngIf="receiverForm$ | async as receiverForm" [formGroup]="receiverForm">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="nameR" class="form-control" formControlName="nameR" placeholder="* NOMBRE" />
          <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="
              !receiverForm.get('nameR').valid &&
              (receiverForm.get('nameR').touched ||
                receiverForm.get('nameR').dirty)
            ">
            El nombre es requerido, mínimo 3 caracteres.
          </small>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button">
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button [disabled]="receiverForm.invalid" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>

</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

> Here's a [**Sample Working Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngb-modal-create-and-edit-form) for your ref.

Comment: thanks for answer you posible solution @SiddAjmera , to be honest i din't try it because i'm not using Observables